# In a loop, once the "if" condition get ensured, it's just keep doing the statement below the condition regardlessly to the condition. PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write the code that finds the best solution for a linear problem. So, for a specific problem I wrote this:

```
import random

appropriate = 0
x_current = [0,0,0,0,0]
x_candidate = [0,0,0,0,0]
Optimal = []

def constraintsx(x):
    appropriate = 0 
    if 3*x[0] + x[1] + 3*x[2] + 2*x[3] + 4*x[4] < 10:
        appropriate = 1
        if x[2] - x[3] > 0:
            appropriate = 1
            if x[1] - x[4] > 0:
                appropriate = 1
                if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] > 4:
                    appropriate = 1
    return appropriate

def purpose(x):
    FValue = x[0] + 3*x[1] - 2*x[2] + 2*x[3] - x[4]
    return FValue



while True:

    if constraintsx(x_current) == 0:
        break

    else:
        for i in range(0,5):
            x_current[i] = random.randint(0,1)



for k in range(0,10):

    while True:

        for j in range(0,5):
            x_candidate[j] = random.randint(0,1)

        if Kisitx(x_candidate) == 0:

            print(k,"k") #I wrote these prints to see where the problem is 
            print(x_candidate,"candidate")
            print(x_current,"current")
            print(purpose(x_candidate),"candidate")
            print(purpose(x_current),"current\n")

            if purpose(x_candidate)>purpose(x_current):
                  x_current = x_candidate

                  print(purpose(x_current),"\n")

                  break



            break


Optimal = x_current
FValue = purpose(Optimal)
print("The best solution:",Optimal,"\nSolution value=",FValue)
```

But whenever this condition get ensured;

```
if purpose(x_candidate)>purpose(x_current):
      x_current = x_candidate
```

It just keep changes the "x_current" regardlessly to the condition.

So here is the output:

```
0 k
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1] candidate
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] current
-2 candidate
0 current

1 k
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] current
0 candidate
0 current

2 k
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] current
5 candidate
0 current

5 

3 k
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] current
0 candidate
0 current

4 k
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1] candidate
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1] current
2 candidate
2 current

5 k
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1] current
5 candidate
5 current

6 k
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] current
3 candidate
3 current

7 k
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1] current
0 candidate
0 current

8 k
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1] candidate
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1] current
5 candidate
5 current

9 k
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1] candidate
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1] current
1 candidate
1 current

The best solution: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1] 
Solution value= 1
```

As you can see once the condition get ensured,it's just keep changing the "x_current". I'm new in Python and i really don't understand why is it doing this. And i don't know how i can describe this situation, although i tried but i can't find anything like this.

why is it do this? and How i can solve this?

Thank you for your help and attention. Thank you for everything...

Comment: In `Kisitx` why are the if statements below each other, because as soon as the first `if` is true then `uygun` is set to 1, so the later ones don’t do anything useful, and similarly if the first `if` is false then `uygun` never can be 1. So I’d expect those four `if` statements to all be at the same indent as each other.

Comment: `x_mevcut = x_aday` does NOT make a separate copy of `x_aday`.  Both names now refer to the SAME list object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to spot the error for me, especially cause your function names are not self-explainatory. I can imagine you named them in your foreign language. I would recommend writing code entirely in english as it increases the accessibilty of code.

Let's sort out some other concepts you didn't understand first:

```
while True:

    if Kisitx(x_mevcut) == 0:
        break

    else:
        for i in range(0,5):
            x_mevcut[i] = random.randint(0,1)
```

first of all, you preferably want to invert the if/else statement.
The range() function would also work without starting the start step
`range(5)`.
Also, you want to use for-each loops instead of for-loops whenever possible. Problem in this case: Python does not allow you to manipulate elements of the iterable you are currently iterating over. However, you can use enumerate to have an index:

```
while True:

    if Kisitx(x_mevcut) != 0:
        for index, element in enumerate(x_mevcut):
            x_mevcut[i] = random.randint(0,1)
    else:
        break;
```

You also want to avoid using while-loops whenever possible. They can result in infinite loops pretty fast.
I do not know what `Kisitx()` stands for, so I can't help you in that regard. Please give it a self-explainatory name or shortly explain what the function does - or give us code.

```
print(k,"k")
```

while this works, it is better to use formatted strings. It increases readability.
Formatted strings calculate the values between curly brackets in run-time:

```
print(f"{k} k")
```

```
if Amac(x_aday)>Amac(x_mevcut):
                  x_mevcut = x_aday

                  print(Amac(x_mevcut),"\n")

                  break



            break
```

The break in your if-statement is unneccesary, as you have a break statement beneath it anyway.

Comment: Thank you very very much. It really helped a lot. And I'm so sorry about the language i'm gonna change it.

And my goal was solving a linear programming problem. So Kisitx means constraints and Amac refers to Max Z. Again sorry about the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but maybe..

It breaks out of the inner `while True` loop, but continues with the outer `for k` loop.

You can set a flag inside the `if` statement and check for it after the `while` loop:

```py
end_loop = False
for k in range(0,10):

    while True:

        for j in range(0,5):
            x_aday[j] = random.randint(0,1)

        if Kisitx(x_aday) == 0:

            print(k,"k")
            print(x_aday,"aday")
            print(x_mevcut,"mevcut")
            print(Amac(x_aday),"aday")
            print(Amac(x_mevcut),"mevcut\n")

            if Amac(x_aday)>Amac(x_mevcut):
                  x_mevcut = x_aday
                  print(Amac(x_mevcut),"\n")
                  end_loop = True
                  break

            break
    if end_loop:
        break
```